# Extract text between quotes in PHP

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have data that outputs like this:

"Option 1" "Blue" "Tan"

It's all on one line; it's all in one field in my database table. (Please don't ask why) But what I need is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Option 1
    [1] => Blue
    [2] => Tan
)
```

I'm trying this regular expression:

```
    $data = preg_match('/\"([^\"]*?)\"/', $row4['Data'], $matches);
```

But `$matches` only yields the first element like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "Option 1"
    [1] => Option 1
)
```

What do I need to do to get anything in between quotes to be their own separate element in an array?

Comment: Are all those escapes necessary? maybe `'/"([^"]*)"/'`?

Comment: Also, you could handle any escaped quotes inside those values that might be like `\"`, with this expression: `'/"((?:\\"|[^"])*)"/'` - no idea if you might have values like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `preg_match_all()`. `preg_match()` only returns the first match.